# UIView like fancy app profile

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to develop a view with the appearance of the profile view of the app Fancy.

https://appsto.re/es/VA0ry.i

What really troubles me is to do paged horizontal scroll and vertical scroll with paging well as to have the sticky menu like a selector and scroll.

Someone could guide me?

Thanks.

with your advice I have come to create this view:

```
    import UIKit

class DetalleTiendaScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var pagesContainer = DAPagesContainer()

    var sugerencias:MyCompraCollectionViewController!
    var vistaOfertas:OfertasCollectionViewController!



    var ofertasConnection:OfertasConnection = OfertasConnection()
    var sugerenciasConnection = SugerenciasConnection()


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.pagesContainer.setSelectedIndex(pagesContainer.selectedIndex, animated: false)
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        ofertasConnection.activa = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        scrollView.delegate = self
        pagesContainer.willMoveToParentViewController(self)

        //        pagesContainer.setSelectedIndex(1, animated: false)
        var altoNavigation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
        if let navHEit = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height {
            altoNavigation = altoNavigation + navHEit
        }
        var altoTab:CGFloat = 0
        if let b = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height {
            altoTab = b
        }
        pagesContainer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 370, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height+500)
        pagesContainer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight

        pagesContainer.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(pagesContainer.view)



        pagesContainer.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.sugerenciasConnection.getSugerencias()
        self.ofertasConnection.getOfertasOnline(0)



        vistaOfertas = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OfertasCollectionViewController") as! OfertasCollectionViewController
        vistaOfertas.ofertasConnection = self.ofertasConnection
        vistaOfertas.indice = 1

        vistaOfertas.collectionView!.gestureRecognizers = self.scrollView.gestureRecognizers


        sugerencias = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyCompraCollectionViewController") as! MyCompraCollectionViewController
        sugerencias.sugerenciasConnection = self.sugerenciasConnection
        sugerencias.indice = 2


        vistaOfertas.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        sugerencias.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


        vistaOfertas.title = "Ofertas online"
        sugerencias.title = "Sugerencias"

        pagesContainer.viewControllers = [sugerencias,vistaOfertas]
        println(scrollView.contentSize)
        self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
        self.scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func scroll(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 200), animated: true)
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        println(self.scrollView.contentOffset)
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 305 {
            self.scrollView.contentOffset.y = 305
        }
    }
}
```

But when I vistaOfertas scrolling, the scroll is reproduced in vistaOfertas and the ScrollView. Is there any way to prevent scroll is made while the contentOffset of scrollView not have a 305?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not even sure what your question is or what you want. Please can you clarify and provide code of what you have already tried so we can see if you have made any attempt at trying to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really broad question. I would start by implementing the horizontal scroll and the top of the screen. From that point, you can consider adding the vertical scroll to wrap all of the existing content or simply add a pan gesture to take care of the cases in which the user starts to scroll to the top (you'll need to make manual changes to the top of the screen while the user is scrolling/dragging upwards, if you want to make it look and behave like the app you're referring to).

At that point you'll probably start running into issues with the communication between the different gestures / scroll views. One would interrupt the other or maybe "steal" the presses. There are various ways of handling it, depending on the exact issue you'll face. I highly recommend watching [Session 235 (Advanced Scrollviews and Touch Handling Techniques) from WWDC 2014](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/)
It talks exactly about these issues with various gestures and scroll views all working together.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but not quite work for me finish what I get. Is this the correct way to do?

Comment: I'm not sure why you removed this as the right answer or what your exact issue at this point is. Have you watched the WWDC session I referred you to? What you're asking here will take quite a bit of work to achieve. The developers of the Fancy app didn't implement it in a day. It will require more work and research on your side. I was just trying to point you in the right direction. My suggestion is that you start working on this and if you have specific questions, post them and get answers for them...

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally uncheck